# QUnit / Sinon test asynchronous ajax call throws exception if http error

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, exception, qunit

I have a piece of code with a jQuery ajax call that throws an exception if there is a http error.

```
function Locale)() {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.endpoint,
        success: function(data) {
             //do stuff
            },
        error: function(jqxhr, error, serverException) {
            throw new httpErrorException(jqxhr, error, serverException);
        } 
   });
}
```

My exception is nice and simple to make sure its working

```
httpErrorException = function(jqxhr, error, serverException) {
    this.toString = function() {
        return error + ': ' + jqxhr.status + ' ' + serverException
    }
}
```

My test is as follows

```
QUnit.test('test httpErrorException', function(assert) {
    assert.expect(1);
    server.respondWith('GET', '/fake/locale', [500, '', 'Internal Server Error']);
    var done = assert.async();
    assert.throws(
        function() {
            loc = locale(fakeUrl);
        },
        function(err) {
             return err.toString() === 'error: 500 Internal Server Error';
        },
        'it failed'
    );
    done();
});
```

When I run the test I get

```
Uncaught it failed
Expected: function( a ){
    [code]
}
Actual: undefined
```

I have been looking at the Qunit.throws docs at https://api.qunitjs.com/assert/throws and it seems like I am doing things right. I guess it is something to do with the async call but I can't sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your `throw` is inside of a callback function, so it throws from there, *not* from your `locale()` function. You can't use throw/catch from async calls directly. You could look into using Promises, or add another function call inside your `error` callback. to do whatever you need to do, then mock that function in your test.

(Note that this is example code, I have not run it...)

In your SOURCE code:

```
function Locale() {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.endpoint,
        success: function(data) {
             //do stuff
            },
        error: function(jqxhr, error, serverException) {
            handleErrors(jqxhr, error, serverException);
        } 
   });
}
```

function handleErrors(jqxhr, err, ex) { /* ... do whatever ... */ }

Then in your TEST code:

```
QUnit.test('test http errors', function(assert) {
    assert.expect(1);
    server.respondWith('GET', '/fake/locale', [500, '', 'Internal Server Error']);
    var done = assert.async();

    // really you should using something like Sinon to stub functions...
    function handleErrors(jqxhr, err, ex) {
        assert.strictEqual(jqxhr.status, 500);
        done();
    }
    Locale(fakeUrl);
});
```

Note that this is NOT an ideal setup... if that ajax call succeeds (when it *should* fail), your test will simply timeout. Really, you should probably be heading toward using Promises, but this might work for now.